# Date month and year calculation

Tags: c#

I have two dates of the form:

```
Start Date: 2007-03-24 
End Date: 2009-06-26
```

Now I need to find the difference between these two in the following form:

```
2 years, 3 months and 2 days
```

How can I do this in c# windows form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TimeSpan`  to get difference..

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string StartDate = "2007-03-24";
            string EndDate = "2009-06-26";

            System.DateTime firstDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            System.DateTime secondDate = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            System.TimeSpan diff = secondDate.Subtract(firstDate);
            var totalDays = (diff).TotalDays;
            var totalYears = Math.Truncate(totalDays / 365);
            var totalMonths = Math.Truncate((totalDays % 365) / 30);
            var remainingDays = Math.Truncate((totalDays % 365) % 30);
            Console.WriteLine("Estimated duration is {0} year(s), {1} month(s) and {2} day(s)", totalYears, totalMonths, remainingDays);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

.net already provide TimeSpan class to show differences between two datetime value.some properties of TimeSpan class show years,month and day interval seperately